# Is it possible to compare 2 different sheets on Excel, update data then insert into a new table all the changes that were made?

Tags: excel, vba

Right now, I have a running list of all my data for the all my products. The list will show an ID that identifies the product and then show the status of that product and the date of that status. Every week I get more data on the same `product_ID` but I am wondering if there is a way to use VBA to update another table to show only one product ID and the most recent status for that? If possible I would then want to insert information into a third table (sheet) that keeps track of the changes made

I am new to using this program and would like to see if this is viable before trying to mess around with it. I hope I explained everything correctly.

Thanks!

Comment: That would actually be a perfect use case for a *real* database (Excel is no database application), where you timestamp your records to have a neat history of changes. You can try to simulate that in Excel with VBA too, it should definitely be possible (with some reasonable effort), but how to do that would highly depend on how your data looks like, how it is structured and how everything works in your proceess (so we cannot answer that more detailed, it is a way too broad). See [ask].

Comment: Thank you PEH. Would you recommend a database to use for this?

Comment: That's actually your decision, we cannot tell that, it depends on many other things like how your data looks like and how it will be processed (that's more asking for an opinion, which we cannot really answer here).